# Finding an Inverse Function and Composition of Functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics

The functions of each pair are inverse to each other. For each pair, check that both compositions give the identity function.

$F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $F^{−1}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are defined by $F(x)=3x+2$ and $F^{−1}(y)=\dfrac{y−2}{3}$. for all y ∈ R

My attempt:

Inverse Function

For each particular but arbitrarily chosen $y \in \mathbb{R}$, according to the definition of $f^{-1}$, $f^{-1}(y) = \dfrac{y-2}{3}$ is a unique real number $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.
\begin{align*}
F(x) & = y\\
3x + 2 & = y\\
x & = \frac{y-2}{3}
\end{align*}
Therefore, $f^{-1}(y) = \frac{y-2}{3}$.

Compositions of Functions

The functions $g \circ f$ and $f \circ g$ are defined as follows:
$$(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(3x + 2) = 3x + 2$$ 
for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: @memerson check my answer bro that correct ?

Comment: What is $g$. Also, you should try to format your math using MathJax. [Here's a quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @memerson just like g(x) and f(x), from my answer g ◦ f is be read g circle f

Comment: Yes but his point is which function are you choosing to be $g$ in this case. Then follow the definition of composition with your two functions. If you get the identity function your successful. You haven’t yet.

Comment: @T.M.  for all y ∈ R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider some definitions.

**Definition.**  Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets.  Let $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$ be functions.  The *composition* of functions $g$ and $f$ is the function $g \circ f: A \to C$ defined by $(g \circ f)(a) = g(f(a))$.

**Definition.**  Let $f: A \to B$ be a function.  Then $g: B \to A$ is said to be the *inverse function* of $f$ if 
\begin{align*}
(g \circ f)(a) & = a & \text{for each $a \in A$}\\
(f \circ g)(b) & = b & \text{for each $b \in B$}
\end{align*} 
If $g$ is the inverse of $f$, we write $g = f^{-1}$, where $f^{-1}$ is read $f$ inverse.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $f(x) = 3x + 2$.  Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $g(y) = \frac{y - 2}{3}$.  To show that $f$ and $g$ are inverses, we must show that $(g \circ f)(x) = x$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $(f \circ g)(y) = y$ for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then
\begin{align*}
(g \circ f)(x) & = g(f(x)) && \text{by definition}\\
               & = g(3x + 2) && \text{substitute $3x + 2$ for $f(x)$}\\
               & = \frac{3x + 2 - 2}{3} && \text{substitute $3x + 2$ for $x$ in the definition of $g$}\\
               & = \frac{3x}{3} && \text{simplify}\\
               & = x && \text{simplify}
\end{align*}
Hence, $(g \circ f)(x) = x$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

It remains to show that $(f \circ g)(y) = y$ for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then 
\begin{align*}
(f \circ g)(y) & = f(g(y)) && \text{by definition}\\
               & = f\left(\frac{y - 2}{3}\right) && \text{substitute
$\frac{y - 2}{3}$ for $g(y)$}\\
               & = 3\left(\frac{y - 2}{3}\right) + 2 && \text{substitute $\frac{y - 2}{3}$ for $x$ in the definition of $f$}\\
               & = y - 2 + 2 && \text{simplify}\\
               & = y && \text{simplify}
\end{align*}

Comment: no how do that for (f∘g)  ?

Comment: I am add missing statement that is  for all y ∈ R , sorry that is same with your answers ?@N. F. Taussig

Comment: I have edited my solution.  Saying for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to saying for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site using MathJax.