# Finding an Inverse Function and Composition of Functions? I add for all y ∈ R

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics

The functions of each pair are inverse to each other. For each pair, check that both compositions give the identity function.

$F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $F^{−1}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are defined by $F(x)=3x+2$ and $F^{−1}(y)=\dfrac{y−2}{3}$, for all $y \in \Bbb{R}.$

My attempt:

Inverse Function

For each particular but arbitrarily chosen $y \in \mathbb{R}$, according to the definition of $f^{-1}$, $f^{-1}(y) = \dfrac{y-2}{3}$ is a unique real number $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.
\begin{align*}
F(x) & = y\\
3x + 2 & = y\\
x & = \frac{y-2}{3}
\end{align*}
Therefore, $f^{-1}(y) = \frac{y-2}{3}$.

Compositions of Functions.

The functions $g \circ f$ and $f \circ g$ are defined as follows:
$$(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(3x + 2) = 3x + 2$$ 
for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is $g$ here?

Comment: @drhab                          (g ◦ f )(x) = g( f (x)) for all x ∈ X,
where g ◦ f is read “g circle f ” and g( f (x)) is read “g of f of x.” The function g ◦ f is called the composition of f and g.

Comment: I know, but in the last lines of your question $g$ just seems to fall from the sky. Further it is said that $g(3x+2)=3x+2$ which implies that $g$ is the identity. Is that really what you meant to say?

Comment: yes @drhab , is the composition  of function above correct?

Comment: If $f$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto3x+2$ and $g$ is the identity function then $g\circ f$ is indeed prescribed by $x\mapsto 3x+2$. Actually then $g\circ f=f$. But I do not see any functionality of this in this context.

Comment: @drhab how about (f∘g)  ? , prescribed by   x↦1/3(x−2)?

Comment: No. If $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is the identity function then $g\circ f=f=f\circ g$

Comment: oke thank you @drhab

Comment: You are not supposed to ask the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986479/finding-an-inverse-function-and-composition-of-functions) twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well then you must check whether the functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto3x+2$ and $x\mapsto\frac13(x-2)$ are inverses of each other.

That is indeed the case since their compositions are prescribed by: $x\mapsto3x+2\mapsto\frac13((3x+2)-2)=x$ and: $x\mapsto\frac13(x-2)\mapsto3(\frac13(x-2))+2=x$ so both are identity functions.

This observation is **enough** to conclude that the functions are inverses of each other, and is what you are asked to do.